# destination path for move_uploaded_file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to know what to use for a destination path for PHP's move_uploaded_file function.
(see http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Right now, I have code that works fine. My domain's root directory contains the following items (among others):
uploads     <-this is a folder
add-photo-submit.php    <-this is a PHP file that uses move_uploaded_file

In add-photo-submit.php, I have the following line of code:

```
$target_path = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
```

$target_path is used as the destination parameter for the function.
This works just fine when I access the file through www.mydomain.com/add-photo-submit.php

However, I recently changed the .htaccess file to remove the .php and add a trailing slash.
Now the PHP file is accessed at www.mydomain.com/add-photo-submit/
I think the PHP file is interpreting the target path as "www.mydomain.com/add-photo-submit/uploads/filename.jpg"

I tried using an absolute path, but it said I didn't have permission...

In the future I would like my root directory to be setup like this:
root
 -admin (folder)
    -add-photo-submit.php
 -uploads

What frame of reference does move_uploaded_file have?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use document_root to get absolute path like this:

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
```

Comment: OR you can use PHP constant, `__DIR__` as an alternative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`...

Answer (score 3):

PHP's local filename operations have no idea what mod_rewrite did to your urls, and deal only with actual raw file system paths. You could have mod_rewrite turn your nice simple `example.com/index.php` into a hideous `example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/yz` and PHP would still be running in the same physical directory on the server.

If the PHP script lives at `/home/sites/example.com/html/index.php`, and you use `uploads/example.jpg` as your move path, then PHP will attempt to put that image into `/home/sites/example.com/html/uploads/example.jpg`, regardless of what the requested URL was.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of server root
 declare below line in any of **root** file(index.php)

```
$_SESSION["uploads_base_url"]=dirname(__FILE__);
```

and you can now use this in any files where upload is needed.

```
echo $uploads_base_url=$_SESSION["uploads_base_url"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use

```
$target_path = "../uploads/" . basename($fileUpload['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file_name ="eg-db.sql"; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $target_file =  __DIR__.'/'.$file_name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $target_location = __DIR__."/targetfolder/". pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_BASENAME); 

    echo "<br>";
    if (file_exists($target_file)){  
       echo "<br> file exist <br>";
       if (rename($target_file,$target_location)) 
       {
           echo "<br>done"; 
       }else{
           echo "<br>nothing";
       }  
    }
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.