# can't move image to a folder using move_uploaded_file function

Tags: php, file-upload

I am a beginner in PHP. I am trying to move an image from tmp_name to my desired folder. the data has been successfully updated in the database. but the image is not moved to my **img** folder

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/5a251bdf492fa.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/functions.php on line 113

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php6UtzgY' to 'img/5a251bdf492fa.jpeg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/functions.php on line 113
```

I am using Mac, and I have tried to change the permission of all related folder to read & write (XAMPP folder, htdoc folder ....) , but it still didn't work.

[image]

what went wrong in here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"'img/5a251bdf492fa.jpeg'"*: You should check if this is the correct path in your project and therefore use an absolute path. You may find helpful answer here: [destination path for move uploaded file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320785/destination-path-for-move-uploaded-file-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/5a251bdf492fa.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/functions.php on line 113

I can assume that you have given the relative path for **destination**

You need to specify the **absolute path** to the function. `move_uploaded_file()`

The following line will help you

```
move_uploaded_file($file, dirname(__FILE__) . '/img/' . $file_name);
```

`move_uploaded_file` never creates the folder itself, so you need to create the folder `img` manually.

Comment: Thank you very much Thamaraiselvam, but i got new errors. Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/img/5a2521b76354a.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/functions.php on line 112

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php3xOkT0' to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/img/5a2521b76354a.jpeg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/functions.php on line 112

Comment: Are you sure following path exist ? `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpdasar/pertemuan13/‌​img/`

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` never creates the folder itself, so you need to create the folder `img` manually

Comment: Awesome, Upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you!