# Image upload into database not saved in directory

Tags: php, html, file-upload, path, image-uploading

I am trying to add a new course into my database with some image and video. I've done it before and it succeeded, but then I create a new project and copy/paste all the folder in my old project into it, it did not work.

#### HTML

```html
<html>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <strong>Basic Form</strong> Elements
          </div>
          <div class="card-body card-block">
            <form action="index.php?admin=addcourse1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

              <div class="row form-group">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="hidden" name="courseID" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="file-input" class=" form-control-label">Icon</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="courseIcon" class="form-control-file">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="text-input" class=" form-control-label">Title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="text" id="text-input" name="courseTitle" placeholder="Text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="textarea-input" class=" form-control-label">Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <textarea name="courseDesc" id="textarea-input" rows="9" placeholder="Content..." class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="file-input" class=" form-control-label">Video</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="courseVideo" class="form-control-file">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="textarea-input" class=" form-control-label">Video Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <textarea name="courseVideoDesc" id="textarea-input" rows="9" placeholder="Content..." class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="text-input" class=" form-control-label">Tagline</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="text" id="text-input" name="courseTagline" placeholder="Text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="file-input" class=" form-control-label">Image</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="courseImage" class="form-control-file">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="textarea-input" class=" form-control-label">Information</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <textarea name="courseInfo" id="textarea-input" rows="9" placeholder="Content..." class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col col-md-3">
                  <label for="text-input" class=" form-control-label">Price</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                  <input type="text" id="text-input" name="coursePrice" placeholder="Text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>




              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
                                        </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset
                                        </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

#### PHP

```html
<?php
include "dbconfig.php";

//icon
$folder ="courses_uploads/"; 

$courseIcon = $_FILES['courseIcon']['name']; 
$path = $folder . $courseIcon ;
$target_file=$folder.basename($_FILES["courseIcon"]["name"]);
$imageFileType=pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 
$allowed=array('jpeg','png' ,'jpg');
$filename=$_FILES['courseIcon']['name'];
$ext=pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 




//video
$courseVideo = $_FILES['courseVideo']['name']; 
$path2 = $folder . $courseVideo ;
$target_file2=$folder.basename($_FILES["courseVideo"]["name"]);
$imageFileType2=pathinfo($target_file2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 
$allowed2=array('mp3','mp4' ,'wma'); 
$filename2=$_FILES['courseVideo']['name'];
$ext2=pathinfo($filename2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 





//image
$courseImage = $_FILES['courseImage']['name']; 
$path1 = $folder . $courseImage ;
$target_file1=$folder.basename($_FILES["courseImage"]["name"]);
$imageFileType1=pathinfo($target_file1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 
$allowed1=array('jpeg','png' ,'jpg');
$filename1=$_FILES['courseImage']['name'];
$ext1=pathinfo($filename1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 







$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO db_course VALUES (:courseID, :courseIcon, :courseTitle, :courseDesc, :courseVideo, :courseVideoDesc, :courseTagline, :courseImage, :courseInfo, :coursePrice)");
$stmt->bindParam(":courseID", $_POST['courseID']);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseIcon", $courseIcon);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseTitle", $_POST['courseTitle']);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseDesc", $_POST['courseDesc']);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseVideo", $courseVideo);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseVideoDesc", $_POST['courseVideoDesc']);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseTagline", $_POST['courseTagline']);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseImage", $courseImage);
$stmt->bindParam(":courseInfo", $_POST['courseInfo']);
$stmt->bindParam(":coursePrice", $_POST['coursePrice']);


if ($stmt->execute() && in_array($ext,$allowed) && in_array($ext1,$allowed1) && in_array($ext2,$allowed2)) {

 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['courseIcon'] ['tmp_name'], $path);
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['courseVideo'] ['tmp_name'], $path2);
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['courseImage'] ['tmp_name'], $path1);
  

 echo "<script>alert('Successful');document.location.href='index.php?admin=course';</script>";
}

else {
 echo "<script>alert('error');document.location.href='index.php?admin=addcourse';</script>";
}
?>
```

#### Error

The problem is, when I click the **add** button, all of the data are saved into database, but the images and video aren't saved into the folder created. I did some research and most of the answers explain that it happened because of the permission, but I already changed it or perhaps i did it wrongly?

Here is the image of the permission that I changed:

[image]

When I run the code, the page just display the error message and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Which error message is displayed?

Comment: I think your error could be related to your usage of relative path, try to use absolute path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320785/destination-path-for-move-uploaded-file-in-php?rq=1

Comment: RT the comment above, and also be careful with the use of `pathinfo()` because if I create a virus or any file whatsoever, I could easily just rename it as a JPG file or whatever your site wants to allow and it will get through. So, I'd use [File Information](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) instead.

Comment: What I mean is that just checking if the file extension is in your array of extensions will not guarantee that the file is actually what you expect.

Comment: @showdev it skip the "if" part and just continue with echo "error" (else {
 echo "<script>alert('error');document.location.href='index.php?admin=addcourse';</script>";
})

Comment: In that case, it seems that one of your conditions is not met: `$stmt->execute() && in_array($ext,$allowed) && in_array($ext1,$allowed1) && in_array($ext2,$allowed2)`. Maybe a file extension is not allowed?

Comment: @catcon I tried the absolute path but it still didnt work. Am i doing it right? ($path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $folder . $courseIcon ;) Sorry for the silly question because i'm new to php :(

Comment: If only the `else` part of your `if` statement is running, then the `move_uploaded_file` part is never executed. I would troubleshoot to see which `if` condition is not met. Try outputting the file extensions to see if they exist in your arrays of allowed extensions.

Comment: @Ana: try var_dump($path) to see the path is correct, I think your `$folder` variable is missing a slash `/`, should be `$folder ="/courses_uploads/"; `

Comment: @zeke Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: @catcon I've tried that also and it still didn't work

Comment: @showdev I'm not sure if i understand what does it mean by outputting the file extensions. Did you mean i should echo $ext; ? I'm so sorry for asking this silly quest

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Or a quick test would be to try: `var_dump(in_array($ext,$allowed)); var_dump(in_array($ext1,$allowed1)); var_dump(in_array($ext2,$allowed2));`. I'm assuming at least one of those is `false`.

Comment: @showdev alright thank you sir. its true that one of the condition is false and now i'm getting it right. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Absolutely! Once you figure out what's going wrong, you can post and accept your own answer, if you like.